# Sharing CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess between two WPF apps

Tags: wpf, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, cefsharp

Can two separate WPF applications share a single instance of CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess?

### Situation

I am converting two WPF applications (a Word and an Outlook Add-In) to use access-tokens to consume a back-end service.

The access-tokens are requested using OpenID Connect Implicit Flow, via a browser, using CefSharp.

### Why share the subprocess?

When the user logs in or out of one Add-In, the same should happen for the other Add-In.  This would work if using a shared subprocess allows the cookies to be shared.

The result I am after is much like a browser with multiple tabs, where cookies received on one tab are shared with the other tabs. Except that in my case the "tabs" are separate WPF applications.

Comment: Technically the `BrowserSubprocess` is a lightweight disposable thing, so your app will likely spawn many in it's lifetime. It's really more the underlying data store that you'd need to share.

You can try sharing the same cookie data store, using something like https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/41/CefSharp.Example/CefExample.cs#L84

There maybe some undesired consequences, so be warned this isn't tired and tested, so may not be supported. (I have a feeling that it's not, though you'll find out soon enough)

Comment: Reading & writing from a shared data store works, but there is some sort of in memory cache which delays writing for 30 seconds (although you can force it) and only reads from the store at startup (I think). So if the two applications are running and a cookie is added by one of them, the other won't know about it until it restarts.  The underlying CEF project does seem to allow for a custom cookie-store, which is beyond me to write.

Comment: You can call `Cef.FlushStore` to manually flush to disk
https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/41/CefSharp.Core/Cef.h#L422

Comment: I guess what I need would be something like `Cef.SyncCacheWithStore` which flushed anything in cache to disk (`Cef.FlushStore`) then read what was on disk back into cache.  I did wonder if `FlushStore` worked two-ways like this, but some quick tests suggests not.

Comment: Anything stopping you from using some form of IPC?

Comment: IPC makes sense as an idea - you mean something like a single WPF application which hosts the browser, then other WPF applications talk to it via IPC when they need to use the browser?  Will look into it, thanks.

Comment: You can try something like https://github.com/red-gate/RedGate.AppHost#redgate-apphost